# Get Roles of logged-in User in Keycloak

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, keycloak

I secured my NODE.js App with keycloak and it works fine

```
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
var session = require('express-session');
var keycloak = null;
var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
keycloak = new Keycloak({
    store: memoryStore
});

app.get('/portal', keycloak.protect(), function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/index.html'));
});
```

in the portal (index.html) I have to show / hide different parts of the page according to the user's role in keycloak. Is there a chance to read the roles of the current user?

Answer (score 8):

the `loadUserInfo` does not provide the roles of the user you may use the keycloak-js and get the roles by `tokenParsed`

```
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-js');
var kc = Keycloak('./keycloak.json');

kc.init().success(function(authenticated) {

   alert(JSON.stringify(kc.tokenParsed)); 

}).error(function() {
            alert('failed to initialize');
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

As of Keycloak-js 11.0.2 (at least) you can directly access array of roles, without parsing the token, by

```
constructor(public keycloakService: KeycloakService) { }
console.log(this.keycloakService.getKeycloakInstance().realmAccess.roles);
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, parsing the `tokenParsed` object does not contain the exact role information user has. It does have the `resource_access` object and inside we can check for the client we are interested in and then the roles. But this may also contains multiple roles assigned for that client.

In such a scenario, the best way is to take advantage of keycloaks user `Attribute` feature.

Simply set an attribute on user level in the attribute tab, such as `prime_role` and value to the role you primarily want to assign to this user.

Then, go to client and in the *Mapper* tab, add new mapper with type `User Attribute`.

This gives you your desired attribute (i.e. `prime_role`) in return when you parse above `tokenParsed` object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
constructor(public keycloakService: KeycloakService) { }
```

```
console.log(this.keycloakService.getKeycloakInstance().tokenParsed['roles']);
```

Then you can see in the console:
[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rXLp.png)