# How can I get user roles from current session?

Tags: java, roles, keycloak, pac4j

After login in my system with Keycloak I want to get the user role-mappings(defined on keycloak admin console) from the user I'm logged in.
I'm able to get the First Name, Last Name, Id, token-id, but when trying to get the roles I get an empty array:

```
private List<KeycloakOidcProfile> getUserData() {
    final PlayWebContext context = new PlayWebContext(ctx(), playSessionStore);
    final ProfileManager<KeycloakOidcProfile> profileManager = new ProfileManager(context);


    System.out.println("Roles->>>"+ profileManager.get(true).get().getRoles()); //here i get -> []
    System.out.println("FirstName->>>"+ profileManager.get(true).get().getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name->>>"+ profileManager.get(true).get().getFamilyName());
    System.out.println("ID->>>"+ profileManager.get(true).get().getId());


    return profileManager.getAll(true);
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Keycloak but don't you need to request roles as a special scope?

Comment: @GabrielPatrício, found same question with Node Js. Have a look on this logic may be that will help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285305/get-roles-of-logged-in-user-in-keycloak

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014894/obtaining-user-roles-in-servlet-application-using-keycloak/38129548

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke can you elaborate a bit more? It's my first experience with Keycloak as well...

Comment: @AmanJaiswal I already checked the second link and my problem is that I'm working with a session not a request so I can't initialize the KeycloakPrincipal

Comment: @GabrielPatrício judging by your method signature it looks like you're using Pac4J, and the OidcConfiguration (and its subclasses) have a scope field that allows you to specify the data you want returned as part of an OIDC login flow. I remember something from the Keycloak admin page that roles is not a default scope, so you need to add that as part of your scope field

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke I figured out what was the problem. in keycloak admin console you have to define the client scopes(roles) to be included in the userinfo, that way you can access by the attribute name defined.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, you should implement your own **AuthorizationGenerator** and attach it to the client (to Keycloak  client in this case) in order to map token roles to 
**KeycloakOidcProfile**, but be sure that **OIP** sends the roles in his token.

There is some glue http://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients.html